# Node.js + Socket.io: Players being transferred from one room to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am creating a multiplayer game using node.js + socket.io. Players are grouped into rooms, with each room having a maximum of 3 players. The algorithm is to keep track of the number of rooms, and check the number of players in the latest room (by the room number). If the number of players in the latest room is over 3, then the program increments the room number, and the next socket / player to join will join a new room ("room"+roomNumber). The problem I'm having is that even though the program correctly has players join a new room when the previous room has 3 players, previous players are being shifted to the new room. I don't see what portion of my code would cause this behavior to happen.

```
var players = [];
var player;
var playerUsernames = [];

var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);

app.use(express.static("public"));

function Player(username) {
    this.username = username;
}

var io = socket(server);
var roomNumber = 1;

setInterval(distributor, 33);

function distributor() {
    io.sockets.in("room" + roomNumber).emit("distributor", players);
}

io.sockets.on("connection", transmitter);

function transmitter(socket) {
    io.of('/').in("room" + roomNumber).clients(function(error,clients){
        var numClients = clients.length;
        if (numClients > 3) {
            roomNumber++;
        }
    });

    io.of('/').in("room" + roomNumber).clients((error, clients) => {
        console.log(clients); // Problem: Displays that players in room 2 include all of the players in room 1
    });

    socket.join("room"+roomNumber);
    socket.on("player", playerMsg);

    function playerMsg(data) {
        player = new Player(data.username);

        if (playerUsernames.indexOf(data.username) == -1 && data.hp == 100) {
            players.push(player);
            playerUsernames.push(data.username);
        }
        else {
            var index = playerUsernames.indexOf(data.username);
            players[index] = player;
        }
    }

    socket.on("players", setPlayers);

    function setPlayers(sentPlayers) {
        players = sentPlayers;
        playerUsernames = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            playerUsernames.push(players[i].username);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's because namespace.clients is asyncronous, and socket.join joins to an old room

So you better update your code to track already joined ppl, to the last room:

```
var roomNumber = 0;
var lastRoomCount = 0;
var maxRoomCount = 3;

function transmitter(cSocket) { // better name it other name than global "var socket"
...
  lastRoomCount=(lastRoomCount+1)%maxRoomCount;
  if (!lastRoomCount) roomNumber++;
  cSocket.join("room" + roomNumber);
...
```